# how to return the second smallest key in a symbol table

Tags: java, linked-list

how do I return the second smallest key in a linked list? I've browsed and didn't see a discussion that really helped me.

```
public class LinkedListST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
    private Node first;      // the linked list of key-value pairs

    // a helper linked list data type
    private class Node {
        private Key key;
        private Value val;
        private Node next;

    public Node(Key key, Value val, Node next)  {
        this.key  = key;
        this.val  = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public Key secondMinKey () {
    if(first == null) return null;
    Node secondMin;

    return null; // TODO
}
```

This is the psuedo code I have so far but I need help turning it into code. Do I have initialize a min and a secondMin node?

EDIT: This is what I have so far

```
public Key secondMinKey () {
  if(first == null) return null;
    Node secondMin;
    for (Node x = first.next.next; x != null; x = x.next) {
        if (need to update min) update min and second min
        else if (need to update second min) update second min
    }
    return second min;
}
```

Comment: you mean you want the second smallest value in an unsorted linked list?

Comment: yes, sorry if it wasnt clear

Comment: `Key` and `Value` are custom classes?

Comment: for every item in my list it needs a key and a value

Comment: Please add the classes.

Comment: Sorry, this is the only thing I have for it. It says The LinkedListST class represents an (unordered) symbol table of generic key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

To find the second smallest element in a linked list, I can think of a decently slick solution. The algorithm kinda goes like this.

Have 2 "pointers". Initialize both to the maximum possible value of `Key`.

```
firstPtr = secondPtr = Key.MAX_VALUE;
```

Parse through the linked list with the following conditions

1. If current `Node.Key` is smaller than `firstPtr`, update both `firstPtr` and `secondPtr` to the current `Node.Key`.
2. Else if the current `Node.Key` is smaller than `secondPtr` then update `secondPtr`.

Let me know if you are having issues coding this up.

Comment: thanks, i have coded what I have so far up there but I still dont understand :/ am I suppose to initialize a new node variable? and do we have to use compareTo, to compare the next node if its smaller or larger? I was thinking i could iterate through the linked list and compare current node to what ever node i am on. and if it is smaller, i would update my key. but im having trouble trying to code that

Comment: @yenyen I think I am kinda getting your confusion. Can you add the `Key` and the `Value` classes?

Comment: i dont think so? I think i just need to know how to update the min and the second min

Comment: Well, the issue is that I don't know what exactly your `compareTo` for `Key` looks like. Either way. You can have two new `Node` variable to be `firstPtr` and `secondPtr`; then, use `compareTo` to see if they are smaller or not. I am afraid I am not able to do much more without see the `Key` class.